# How do you say "function with fewer oscillations?"

Tags: terminology

Say you have a few functions on the same graph that oscillate, but they're *not* sine functions, they're polynomials.

[image: curves]

(These are Legendre polynomials)
How do you refer to the "curvier" ones without sounding too informal?  Is it ok to say "the curves that oscillate faster", even though these are not sinusoids? (I thought only sinusoids really "oscillate")

Comment: Oscillation is closely related with rapid change, rapid change means the derivative is larger (in its absolute value).

Comment: Maybe the word is *frequency*?

Comment: I don't think a polynomial has a _frequency_.. ? These functions are polynomials, so are not periodic, so I do not think they can have _frequency_.

Comment: I've heard of less oscillations being descibed as _smooth_...perhaps "rough" would describe the opposite?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can refer to it as "the curve with more inflection points", "the curve with more extrema", or "the larger degree polynomial".